# Stream computer screen to TV via network instead of a USB wireless link

Tags: streaming, tv, video-streaming, hdtv, screen-sharing

I want to stream my computer screen (not just video or a limited amount of content) to my TV via the network.  I know there are wireless devices that use USB to tranfer the screen to the TV.  However, these are limited to a short distance.  What I want to do is stream the data via the network so I can be anywhere within the network and have the data shown on the tv.  I am looking for video and sound to transfer.  I want the entire computer screen to transfer just like when you connect the computer to the tv via VGA or HDMI and the sound out using the 3.5mm plug.  I have been unable to find a unit that allows for the entire computer screen to transfer via the network.  I just find the ability to stream video.  I am using Windows 7 Ultimate with a quad processor and 16 GB of memory so I have the power to handle the transfer.  My tv is hdtv.

I am looking for something like the Warpia StreamHD Wireless PC to TV Full 1080P but using the network:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B004GTN0T4/ref=asc_df_B004GTN0T41800431?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=asn&creative=395093&creativeASIN=B004GTN0T4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004GTN0T4)

Comment: So you have the network capacity to handle a 5Gbps uncompressed video stream? WOW, and last I checked we were capped at 300 Mbps for the N standard... Disclaimer: 5Gpbs is based on the DVI standard (pre-overhead). Sadly you will have to deal with some kind of compression that is going to slow down responsiveness of the screen. Pretty sure nothing like this exists yet unless you build a cheap linux box and then run VNC (this will stop you from viewing some 3d direct draw applications, particularly games).

Comment: Is that the speed at what a vga cable transfers?  I don't understand all the details of data transfer.  I was just looking for a way to not connect the cable and not be limited to the short distance of the USB wireless devices like the Warpia StreamHD.

Comment: I think that wireless device you linked does not actually use the standard wireless netowrk protocols, as Kyle said, the current bandwidth for those protocols is not sufficient for uncompressed HD streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Get a simple mini computer (< $100). Use HDMI to connect to the TV. Remote into your main computer using VNC. Alternatively, for media files, get a streamer (Popcorn, WD etc.) and use UPnP to stream files to the TV.